# Save in DB 3 images at the same time

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, image, file-upload

I have a basic image upload which is working nice but now I need to save it in my MySql DB 3 images not only one, How can I save 3 images in the same form with my upload script?

I need to save 3 images because is an article blog in my page and I want to show the 3 images in a slider in the preview, so because that, I need to save 3 images in the same id.

Another think is, How can just save one or two without the upload script show me error because one or two or even the three files upload are empty?

Here I show you my upload script:

```
<?php 
    require_once("connection.php");
    require_once("settings.php");
    $alert = "";
    if(isset($_FILES['foto_ser1'])) {
        $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['foto_ser1']['name']);
        $extension = $extension["extension"];
        $allowed_paths = explode(", ", $allowed_ext);
        $valid = 0;
        for($i = 0; $i < count($allowed_paths); $i++) {
            if ($allowed_paths[$i] == "$extension") {
                $valid = 1;
            }
        }
        if ($valid == 1 && $_FILES["foto_ser1"]["size"] <= $max_weight) {
            if (file_exists("../assets/img/servicios/" . $_FILES["foto_ser1"]["name"])) {
                $alert = '<p class="error">' . $_FILES["foto_ser1"]["name"] . ' El nombre del archivo ya existe!' . '</p>';
            } else {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["foto_ser1"]["tmp_name"], "../assets/img/servicios/" . $_FILES["foto_ser1"]["name"]);
                $save1 = $_FILES["foto_ser1"]["name"];
                $statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO SERVICIOS (titulo, descripcion, categoria, foto_ser1, foto_ser2, foto_ser3) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                if ($statement->execute(array($_POST['titulo'],$_POST['descripcion'],$_POST['categoria'],$save1,$save2,$save3))); 
                $dbSuccess = true; 
                $alert = '<p class="ok">' . ' Servicio agregado satisfactoriamente!' . '</p>';
                $dbh = null;
            }
        } else {
            $alert = '<p class="error">' . ' Tipo de archivo inv&aacute;lido!' . '</p>';
        }
    }
?>
```

form page.php:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="servicios" name="data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <fieldset>
            <?php echo $alert1; ?>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-4"><?php echo $translate->__('Title'); ?> :</label>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="titulo" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-4"><?php echo $translate->__('Article info'); ?> :</label>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <textarea id="maxlength_textarea" class="form-control" maxlength="225" name="descripcion" /></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-4"><?php echo $translate->__('Article category'); ?> :</label>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="categoria" />
                </div>
            </div>                  
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-4"><?php echo $translate->__('File to upload 1'); ?> :</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input name="foto_ser1" type="file" />
                </div>
            </div>                  
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-4"><?php echo $translate->__('File to upload 2'); ?> :</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input name="foto_ser2" type="file" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-4"><?php echo $translate->__('File to upload 3'); ?> :</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input name="foto_ser3" type="file" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-sd-offset-9 col-md-12"><br />
                            <button class="btn btn-info" name="enviar"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> <?php echo $translate->__('Save'); ?></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>          
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <div id="loading" style="display:none;"><img src="assets/img/ajax_loader.gif" /></div>
```

EDIT

---

The new code:

```
<?php 
    require_once("includes/connection.php");
    require_once("includes/settings.php");
    $alert = "";
    if(isset($_FILES['foto_ser{$i}'])) {
        for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
            if ($_FILES["foto_ser{$i}"]['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

                if ($valid == 1 && $_FILES["foto_ser{$i}"]["size"] <= $max_weight) {
                    if (file_exists("assets/img/servicios/" . $_FILES["foto_ser{$i}"]["name"])) {
                        $alert = '<div class="alert alert-block alert-danger fade in">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
                    <h4 class="alert-heading">Error!</h4>
                    <p>' . $_FILES["foto_ser{$i}"]["name"] . ' El nombre de la foto ya existe!' . '</p></div>';
                    } else {
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["foto_ser{$i}"]["tmp_name"], "assets/img/servicios/" . $_FILES["foto_ser{$i}"]["name"]);
                        $save1 = $_FILES["foto_ser{$i}"]["name"];
                        $save2 = $_FILES["foto_ser{$i}"]["name"];
                        $save3 = $_FILES["foto_ser{$i}"]["name"];
                        $activo = is_array($_POST['activo'])
                            ? implode(', ', $_POST['activo'])
                            : $_POST['activo'];
                        $statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO SERVICIOS (titulo_ser, stitulo_ser, servicios, precio, foto_ser1, foto_ser2, foto_ser3, categoria, subcategoria, visto, activo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                        if ($statement->execute(array($_POST['titulo_ser'],$_POST['stitulo_ser'],$_POST['servicios'],$_POST['precio'],$save1,$save2,$save3,$_POST['categoria'],$_POST['subcategoria'],$_POST['visto'],$activo))); 
                        $dbSuccess = true; 
                        $alert = '<div class="alert alert-block alert-success fade in">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
                        <h4 class="alert-heading">Success!</h4>' . ' Nuevo servicio agregado satisfactoriamente!' . '</p></div>';
                        $dbh = null;
                    }
                } else {
                    $alert = '<div class="alert alert-block alert-danger fade in">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
                    <h4 class="alert-heading">Error!</h4>
                    <p>' . ' Tipo de imagen inv&aacute;lida!' . '</p></div>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Use `blueimp` http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ for multiple upload

Answer (score 0):

You need to have upload handling. Right now your code is simply ASSUMING that all uploads will always succeed. Indeed, it assumes there will NEVER not be an upload.

In short, you need something like this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
   if ($_FILES["foto_ser{$i}"]['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
       ...file #$i has succeeded...
   }
}
```

Your code is also quite dangerous - you're directly using the user-provided `['name']`parameter in your `move_uploaded_files` call, which allows a malicious user to scribble a file of their choosing ANYWHERE on your server.

Comment: HI, I change the code with yours and delete a couple of thinks too... not give me error in my fiddler show me the upload script with all inputs also the 3 images but in the DB not save me nothing.. In edit line show you how I change the code... maybe you can see my error